# How should I escape a comma inside the arguments to esyscmd?

Tags: autoconf, m4

I have an M4 macro that is using `esyscmd` to generate a list:

```
pushdef([FILES], esyscmd(echo \"\(\'`find test-photos -type f | paste -sd '\t' - | sed "s/\t/\',\'/g"`\'\)\"))dnl
```

Leaving aside that this is probably a terrible idea and is being done as a conscious exercise in abusing the autoconf system, how do I successfully escape the `,` character in the `sed` regexp, such that M4 won't interpret it as an argument separator in the `esyscmd` call?

Currently I get:

```
/usr/bin/m4:configure.ac:8: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `esyscmd' ignored
```

... regardless of how I attempt to escape the `,`.  Replacing the `,` with a *different* character works just fine.  E.g. using a `.` gets me:

```
('test-photos/foo'.'test-photos/bar')
```

Comment: Quote the entire argument to `esyscmd` using [ and ].

Comment: @markasoftware Please submit the above as an answer, & I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As configured in autoconf, the M4 quote characters are `[` and `]`. Commas inside a quote will not be interpreted as argument separators. Thus you should simply quote the command you are passing to `esyscmd`, by surrounding it with `[` and `]`.

Unlike in other programming languages you may be used to, quoting doesn't make the argument a string or anything like that -- quoting is simply a way to treat some text as fixed, and not to interpret macros or special characters within that text.

The [M4 manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Quoted-strings) is really the only way to learn about M4.